# Implementing Excel formula in VBA

Tags: vba

I have this Excel formula which I would like to implement via VBA, unfortunately it keeps yielding an error.

My Excel formula:

```
      IF(isemptyornothing(A1:A50); ""; IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1:A50)); VALUE(A1:A50); A1:A50))
```

My VBA attempt:

```
    Range("B1:B50").Formula = _
  "=IF(IsEmptyorNothing(A1:A50), "", IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1:A50)), VALUE(A1:A50), A1:A50))"
```

This yields the following error:

"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Being a novice in VBA, I am not sure what to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`""` needs to be `""""`

Also the formula you show would need to be array entered, but you can simple do this:

```
Range("B1:B50").Formula = _
  "=IF(IsEmptyorNothing(A1), """", IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1)), VALUE(A1), A1))"
```

And Excel will put adjust the A1 as the formula is copied down, automatically.

This assumes that `IsEmptyorNothing` is a UDF, because no such formula exists in standard Excel.

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. As for `IsEmptyorNothing`, oddly enpough it was on my Excel already, or at least I didn't define it.